# How to read push notifications sent to Selenium Chrome Driver?

Tags: python, selenium, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Using Selenium Python with the Chrome Driver, I have a site that I do not own loaded that periodically sends me Push Notifications. I need to be able to read the text content of said notifications whenever they are received. How can I do this?

EDIT: Talking about these kind of notifications.
[Push Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg8J2.png)

Comment: Can you share the code which you tried? Also, could you share the URL?

Comment: The website is instagram.com. I have selenium setup to the point that I can log in and receive push notifications, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to read them, hence no code.

Comment: Is that Push notification appearing as an alert window? If yes, switch to the alert and read the text  from it.  If you are unsure on when this alert might appear, use Explicitwait to wait until the alert is available and then perform the actions.

Comment: It is not an alert window. It is those type of notifications that use the native notification prompt of the OS.

Comment: @jad did you ever get this to work? I'd like to do something similar

Comment: I would also like to do something similar! Any luck?